# ffmpeg concat loses audio after first clip only in browser, audio plays good on player like vlc etc

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg, terminal, mp3

i am trying to combine or concatenate audio file one after other like after concatenation of two audio files, both file will downloaded as a single file wheres audio will be played in a queue one after other.

after some research i found the package FFmpeg i.e dealt with mp3,mp4 etc files.i tried to run FFmpeg commands in terminal but file is created and playing good on VLC but not playing accurately in browser.

**Some Commands tried by me in terminal are as follow :-**

ffmpeg -i "concat:a.mp3|b.mp3" -acodec copy output.mp3

ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy output.mp3

ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -i b.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp3

ffmpeg -y -i "concat:a.mp3|b.mp3" -ar 22050 -ab 512 -b 800k -f mp4 -s 514*362 -strict -2 -c:a aac "OUTPUT.mp4"

Library Link followed by me :- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html

Note :- I am using Ubuntu based system

**file is created successfully from above commands and playing well on VLC player.**

**where in browser first clip is playing well but after first clip browser stops. somehow second audio clip is not playing in browser. i don't know why may be there is same kind of pattern error.**

if anyone can help, i shall be very thankful to him/her.

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using, and how are you playing it in that browser?

Comment: Show complete output of `ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -i b.mp3`

Comment: i am using chrome for testing.

Comment: Complete Ouput Screenshot :- https://prnt.sc/pebfb0

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pebfhp